# GET call with a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sqlite, express

I want to create a NodeJS-program that serves a JSON-aray from a database. I am using express, sqlite and sqlite3 packages. When I the code run it in the terminal, I get this output:

```
$ node index.js
[
  { Field1: 'Stockholm', Field2: '123' },
  { Field1: 'Gothenburg', Field2: '123' },
  { Field1: 'London', Field2: '123' }
]
```

It displays the correct data.

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const sqlite = require('sqlite')
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')

const app = express()

let database

sqlite
  .open({ driver: sqlite3.Database, filename: 'test.sqlite' })
  .then((database) => {
    database.all('SELECT * FROM cities').then(rows => {
        console.log(rows)      
      })
  })

  app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    database.all('SELECT * FROM cities').then(cities => {
      response.send(cities)
    })
  })

  app.listen(3000)
```

When I run the code above, on `http://localhost:3000` I get an error message saying:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined`

I want to display the same data as is displayed in the terminal/console on `http://localhost:3000`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: As the message indicates, `database` is undefined in your `get` method, and you're trying to call method `.all` on something that's undefined. I don't see anywhere in your code where you set the value of `database`. It's only defined within the scope of the `.then(...)` method on your `.open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database will be initialized in an async manner so you should wait til you have an instance of database, and save it.

```
const express = require('express')
const sqlite = require('sqlite')
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')

const app = express()

let globalDatabase

sqlite
  .open({ driver: sqlite3.Database, filename: 'test.sqlite' })
  .then((database) => {
    if(database){
      database.all('SELECT * FROM cities').then(rows => {
        console.log(rows)      
      })
      globalDatabase = database
    }

  })

  app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    if(globalDatabase) {
      globalDatabase.all('SELECT * FROM cities').then(cities => {
        response.send(cities)
      })
    }else{
       // todo whatever you want send error, or wait for db or initialize it again
    }

  })

  app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I want to make it so my code makes a POST-call to localhost, which adds a city (name value and a population value from a JSON-object which is sent in the calls' body) in the cities-table. Like this: `{ "name": "Test city", "population": 123 }` How do I do that?

Comment: You need to add a new endpoint like `app.post("/addCity",(req, res) => {
// read req.body for incoming parameters and use your db to save it. 
})`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `database` is coming up undefined as you are using it in a promise but not assigning it.  You can resolve your issue the following way:

```
let database

sqlite
  .open({ driver: sqlite3.Database, filename: 'test.sqlite' })
  .then((db) => {
    // assign it here
    database = db;
    database.all('SELECT * FROM cities').then(rows => {
       console.log(rows)      
    })
  })
```

You'd then be able to use it later.  Just remember that this promise will need to resolve prior to requests going to your GET endpoint, or else they will fail as well. Hope this helps

Comment: This worked, but I'm stuck when trying the following: I want to make it so my code makes a POST-call to localhost, which adds a city (name value and a population value from a JSON-object which is sent in the calls' body) in the cities-table. Like this: { "name": "Test city", "population": 123 } How do I do that?